# Line breaks using htmlspecialchars?

Tags: php, html

I have a form that people can enter text into and it echoes to a page. I'm using htmlspecialchars for obvious reasons, but currently this doesn't allow for line breaks.

If someone types:

```
 "Line one
 Line two"
```

It comes out as:

```
 "Line one Line two"
```

But I'd like to keep the linebreaks in there.

Here's how my data is being echoed:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($row["message"]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `nl2br` function.

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php after the `htmlspecialchars` other wise the line breaks will be escaped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do this using PHP funcition nl2br() http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php.

```
echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row["message"]));
```